# How can I use data in an ng-if?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use data in a repeat to select an item in another array.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="event in eventDates" ng-if="eventToggles.{{event.eventName}}">
```

Is this possible? What's the proper syntax?

Comment: is `eventToggles` in scope?

Comment: @xyz why did you delete your answer? It's correct.

Comment: @xyz Yes, for instance, this works: <ion-item ng-if="eventToggles.valentinesDay">

Comment: @JBNizet, i thought i misunderstood the question. Anyway, its good that dangnelson got solution from idmean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have to use plain old JavaScript syntax:

```
ng-if="eventToggles[event.eventName]"
```

Comment: Well that's easy. Thanks!